# Adding Entire File into PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, file, sorting

I have been attempting to write a website that processes names of people and reads them back in a list, so I can do other things with them later.  I need them to be alphabetized, and show up with each person on their own line.  Kind of like this:

[1]  Doe--John

[2]  Washington--George

[3]  Zekeman--William

I have created a php script that uses an array to sort the names; it is in the file *sort.php*.  I have created a file for the people, called *students.html*.  These names were fed in from a form.

To display the name on the webpage, I created a simple php include function.

Here is my coding:

**Sort.php**

```
    <?php

        $filename = "students.html"

        $names = array file( string $filename );
        sort($names);
        foreach ($names as $key => $val) {
              echo "[" . $key . "] " . $val . "\n";
        }

    ?>
```

**Students.html**

```
    "Washington--George",
    "Zekeman--William",
    "Doe--John",
```

**Webpage**

```
   <?php include 'sort.php';?>
```

Everything works perfectly, except the webpage displays this error:

**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in **/home/www/the/path/to/my/directory/sort.php** on line **3**

I have played with it and I cannot figure out how to fix the error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Note:  I apologize if this makes no sense.  I am brand new to this.

Comment: did you check your code properly ?? i think u are missing semicolon in you code??

Comment: missing ";" in first line after closing "".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the end of `$filename = "students.html"` you need to put a `;`

Edit: also `$names = file($filename);`

Answer (score 4):

```
$names = array file( string $filename );
```

This is wrong. You need to remove both `array` and `string`.

Comment: And he also miss a `;` on the previous line.

Comment: Right, I saw after posting my comment.

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
<?php

$filename = "students.html";

$names = file( $filename );
sort($names);
foreach ($names as $key => $val) {
    echo "[" . $key . "] " . $val . "\n";
}

?>
```